# How to call function from Stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen many questions similar to mine in Stack Overflow but it did not fit my case since they were asking to call `function` from - to `Stateful` widget.

I want call function located into `State Full` widget from a non `Stateful-Stateless Widget`

My code is complicated, I will try to explain it below:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  void myFunction(){
    print('hello dart');
  }
  ShowDialog showDialog = ShowDialog();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: (){
        showDialog.myDialog();
      },
        child: Text('tab me')
    );
  }
}


class ShowDialog {

  Widget myDialog(){
    return showDialog(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return SimpleDialog(
                  
                  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                  titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18),
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                         // here i need to call myFunction() Methood 
                        },
                        child: const Text("tab")
                    ),
                  ],
                )
      },
    );
  }

}
```

How can I go through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can call it directly like this:

```
_ExampleState().myFunction();
```

The full code:

```
class Example  extends StatefulWidget {
    const Example ({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

      final String title;

      @override
      State<Example > createState() => _ExampleState ();
    }

    class _ExampleState  extends State<Example > {
    
      void myFunction(){
        print('hello dart');
              }
      ShowDialog showDialog = ShowDialog();

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(

            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                showDialog.myDialog(context);
              },
              child: Text('tab me')
          )
        );
      }
    }


    class ShowDialog {

      Future myDialog(BuildContext context){
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return SimpleDialog(

              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
              titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18),
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // here i need to call myFunction() Methood
                      _ExampleState().myFunction();
                    },
                    child: const Text("tab")
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }

    }
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: How you did that ? it give me red error line if i use it direct !! –

Comment: red error line where ?

Comment: under _ExampleState . but i noticed if this class was in the same where myFunction() located  there no red line but when i move the class to a separated file so the red line show again , any idea why

Comment: yes if you put the ShowDialog class in a separate file then it will give you a red line under _ExampleState because it's in another file and it's private, but if you rename the class and make it public by removing the underscore like this : (ExampleState), now you can import it and call it anywhere.

Comment: thank you so mush i just learned this from you , and sorry to @h8moss to take mark answer from him and give it to you , his answer also good but with high compute with his way if i am not wrong

Comment: I'm happy to help, his answer is good too, in some cases I would use his method instead mine, and I do it all the time when I need to use different functions so I have to pass a different function as a parameter each time: myDialog(VoidCallback function), but if there is only one function,I would call it directly inside the onPressed: (){}, So use what suits you

Comment: you know , you right , his way is more suit me i just noticed that , my function contains big data and by his way it is setstate the state direct after finishing the finction , but yours just proceed but didn't setstate the state , even though the function its self contains setstate , i can't understand why Lol i coming back to his way

Comment: check my new answer

Answer (score 1):

So in order to have your `showDialog` function call `MyFunction`, you need to pass it as if it was a callback.

To do that, first add a `Function` callback in your class:

```
class ShowDialog {
ShowDialog({required this.callback});

VoidCallback callback;


...
}
```

Then you have to pass the callback when you create the object:

```
ShowDialog showDialog = ShowDialog(callback: myFunction);
```

You actually can't do that tho, because this is a class variable, a simple solution is to turn your `showDialog` variable into a getter, this means `showDialog` will compute again every time you call it, which is not ideal but I don't think it will be terrible for this specific use-case.

```
ShowDialog get showDialog => ShowDialog(callback: myFunction);
```

note the get keyword and the `=>` instead of an equal sign

### EDIT:

You can also pass the callback as part of the `myDialog` method, this is probably actually a better idea:

```
Widget myDialog(VoidCallback callback) {
    return showDialog(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return SimpleDialog(
                  
                  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                  titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18),
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: callback,
                        child: const Text("tab")
                    ),
                  ],
                )
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Avoid using unnecessary statements. that's happen under callback into button method , however it did not call the function

Comment: Could you try putting it like this `onPressed: callback,`? and seeing if it works?

Comment: thanks it is work by callback(); .. but are you sure that ShowDialog get showDialog => ShowDialog(callback: myFunction); is same ShowDialog showDialog = ShowDialog(callback: myFunction); .. because it accept the first one not second one

Comment: not : i have big data in that ShowDialog class

Comment: They are the same in terms of function, as in, they both archive the same thing, but only the one with get works, this has to do with the way classes are built

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that returns a Dialog in a separate file :

```
  Future myDialog({required BuildContext dialogContext, required Function function}){
      return showDialog(
          context: dialogContext,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return SimpleDialog(

              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
              titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red, fontSize: 18),
              children: [
               ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      function();
                    },
                    child: const Text("tab")
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
```

then I made 2 functions, the first one just print (Hello first function) and the second function print (Hello Second function) and set the state and rebuild the widget tree

I made 2 TextButton: the first TextButton call the myDialog function and pass the firstFunction as a parameter, the second TextButton call the myDialog function and pass the secondFunction as a parameter :

the code :

```
class ExampleState  extends State<Example > {

    void firstFunction(){
        print('Hello first function');
      }

      void secondFunction(){
        setState(() {
          print('Hello Second function');
        });

      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print('build');
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(

            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      myDialog(dialogContext: context, function: firstFunction );
                    },
                    child: Text('First Dialog')
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      myDialog(dialogContext: context, function: secondFunction );
                    },
                    child: Text('Second Dialog')
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

notice that I added a print('build'); so I can know when it rebuild the widget tree

The result:

[image]